# Driver loading mechanism Windows vs Linux

Tags: windows, linux, operating-system

Why do we have to restart windows in order to bring newly installed device driver into effect ? How does the driver loading mechanism differ from that of Linux ?

Comment: You *do not* have to reboot Windows in order to install drivers. Only special circumstances require a reboot. Can you clarify your question to better reflect what you're actually asking here?

Comment: I am not aware of the driver loading mechanism in Windows, though after installing a new driver we need to reboot the machine in order to get the driver running, whereas in linux i assume we need not have to it, a normal `lsmod` would do the trick.

Comment: Are you talking about a *specific* driver? Because, no, most Windows drivers *do not* require a restart for installation. Also, isn't `lsmod` just a command to *list* the loaded drivers? How does that install anything?

Comment: Apologies it should have been `modprobe`. My question in windows in general refers to devices which do not support plug and play behavior, like add-on card driver, display driver etc. Broadly I wanted to know the driver loading process in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Windows could load your function driver dynamically by using CreateService and StartService. Also, you can use ZwLoadDriver to load a driver.
But, you have to load some types of driver after restart such as class driver, filter driver etc. Because these drivers are depended on other system drivers. If your driver is loaded too late. Your driver won't work correctly.
For more detail, please check MSDN. You can control the order of driver loading accurately by using registry.